# When dragging an element over, cursor position does not update

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a website that drags an element over to a drop zone. The problem is when you drop an element, a lot stuff in the back end has to update. Due to this, the cursor position won't update until to move the cursor.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt81jhm9/) sort of reproduces the problem

When you drag the line over to the bottom div and don't move the cursor, it still thinks the cursor location is in the original spot before it dragging, so the hover still displays red. Once you move the cursor it updates.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Drag this line</li>
</div>
<br><br />
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'link'
          ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);

        }

        function drop(ev) {
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
          
          var lag = 0 //This just simulates a lot of things going on, not really real code
          for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            lag += i
            lag /= 2
            console.log(lag)
          }
          
          ev.target.innerHTML = "If you don't move your mouse, it'll still be hovering over the line, if you move the mouse it updates"
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
```

EDIT: I tried

```
html.busy, html.busy * {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```

in the CSS
This helped the issue, but some rare moments it doesn't work and it also doesn't work when you have a `window.alert()` when you drop it,
shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dj6uxsLb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better use `dragend` or `dragleave` event listener.
not `:hover`.

See the difference as you try it.

`dragend` will work the way you want it to.
However, if you drag the `li` to a place other than `div2`, it returns and then the red color disappears.

```
item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
  this.classList.remove('hover');
});
```

`dragleave` will remove red color when your mouse leave original `li` element.

```
item.addEventListener('dragleave', function () {
  this.classList.remove('hover');
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k70havq5/6/).

I annotated the two codes. Release one by one and look at the difference.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#div1 li").forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    this.classList.add("hover");
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    this.classList.remove("hover");
  });
  
  
  item.addEventListener("dragend", function () {
    this.classList.remove("hover");
  });
  
  /** If you use dragleave, red color will disappeared when you leave original li element. */
  /* 
  item.addEventListener('dragleave', function () {
    this.classList.remove('hover');
  });
  */
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "link";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

  var lag = 0; //This just simulates a lot of things going on, not really real code
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    lag += i;
    lag /= 2;
    console.log(lag);
  }
  /* window.alert("just another lag") */
  ev.target.innerHTML =
    "If you don't move your mouse, it'll still be hovering over the line, if you move the mouse it updates";
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Drag this line</li>
</div>
<br><br />
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: I actually already used .onmouseover and .onmouseout to change the css of other elements, but the answer made me realize I can manually trigger .onmouseout using Jquery, so it sort of solves the problem.

Comment: @BinaryCubed Happy for solved, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. or You can answer yourself and adopt the answer to finish the question.